# Android send string over 3g

Tags: android, network-programming, 3g

I'm trying to send a simple string from an android device to a pc.
I managed to send the string via wifi (because is on a LAN network), but the code doesn't work over 3g.
The code i'm using is this:

```
class send extends AsyncTask
        {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {

                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("IP here")
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8564);
                    String message = "sample_message";
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                        out.println(message);   

                    } catch(Exception e) {}
                    finally {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you're using wifi or other network type. Are you getting any `Exception` while using 3g?

Comment: it doesn't seem to give any exception

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` to each `catch` statement and see if it shows in logcat any `Exception`.

Comment: i added a Toast.makeText() in each catch statement instead of a e.printStackTrace(), because i'm trying the program on the device by exporting the program, not on the emulator. This is because i need to test the 3g connection with the sim and because eclipse doesn't recognize my device as an AVD (I got the debugging mode on), so i can't test it directly, but only by exporting the APK. However the toast doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your PC connected? Is it a LAN behind NAT? Are you using the LAN IP address as serverAddr? What is "IP here"?

If you are using a local network IP address behind the NAT you'll never be able to connect.

If you have a router/wifi AP, enable port forwarding to you PC and use the public IP address provided by the ISP as serverAddr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating  a `DataOutputStream` like

```
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(message + '\n');
```

Instead of :

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                        out.println(message);
```

Comment: Nothing changes... when i click the send button there's no exception and the program keep running, but the pc doesn't receive anything

Comment: If i click the button, nothing instantly happens, but if i wait a pair of minutes, maybe less, the program crashes...what can be the problem?

Comment: Try to log the exception in the last block and post it to the question

Comment: As i said in @piotr post, i'm trying the program by exporting the APK to the device, because Eclipse doesn't recognize the device as an AVD and i need to try the 3g connection, so i cannot even run it on an emulator